Pine script to Find a closest value among a list of values
Request to review the below model
enter image description here
the averages were assigned in as A1, A2, A3 already
I wish to find the closest value to 0 among the array of average values and return as A1, because -4 is the closest value in my model
I tried math.min (math.abs(a1-0), math.abs(a2-0), math.abs(a3-0)....
And it is returning as 4. I wish to have -4 and related assigned value as A1
Request to give a pine script code for the same.

What are a1, a2, a3.. etc? Which one is the array that you want to use in your search?

Try giving requests to ChatGPT. What have you tried so far?

HI, a1, a2, a3 are the calculated values of averages, assigned as a variable. I expect to plot line on a1 value -4, which is closest to zero
